# ANTLR Lexical Modes for complex grammar

Tags: antlr4

I am faced with syntax that allows for multiple formats of parameters, for example

```
OpenFile FILE=filename
OpenFile FILE=(filename)
OpenFile filename
```

Parsing the variants is a no-brainer, but ... (there is always a BUT, isn't it ?)

"filename" can contain strange symbols, replacement tags, yada, yada, so it's difficult to impossible to define a clear, single lexer token for it, I always run into ambiguities, so I'd need to get that parameter as a raw string without further tokenizing.

While it wouldn't be too difficult to switch to a "raw" Lexical Mode and switch back on a NL or the closing paren for the first two formats I just can't think of a way for the 3rd format, when I switch on the OpenFile token itself FILE= etc. would be considered part of the raw string for the other formats.

Comment: Is this the only input you have to parse or can this get more complex? If that's the only one I wouldn't even consider a dedicate parser for it, but read the in put line-by-line and split it on equal signs and/or space chars.

Comment: Of course not ;-)

This isn't the only input by far, it's just an example, we are talking about a set of 200+ language elements which, I found the hard way, even allows for absurd syntax variants not documented in the 3000+ page manual...

A better (or worse) example would probably have been

"COPY-FILE FROM-FILE=fromfilename,TO-FILE=tofilename" which will also work as "COPY-FILE fromfilename,tofilename" which means I'd even have to exclude the comma from "catch ANY" logic and make it switch back to "filename mode" again immediately, but only in special cases like this, not in general.

Comment: It's always a good idea to give real-life examples in your question, and not dumb-down the input/examples too much. Otherwise you get suggestions that do not hold true for your real language.

Comment: "... not documented in the 3000+ page manual ...", what language are you parsing, if I may ask?

Comment: Not a "language" per se, it's BS2000 JCL.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, scrolled through the specs of it, and perhaps it would be easier to process it line by line... But what do I know, I just quickly scrolled through it :). Best of luck anyway!

Comment: I actually started out that way, but there are statements with VERY complex subparameters and parsing them one by one seemed an even bigger nightmare. The complex syntax is only half the fun, the other half comes with schedulers injecting variables when a job gets submitted, these are tagged with special characters like ^ or even " so complicating things even more, parsing a plain filename wouldn't be a big issue. So I'll take it there's no way doing it the ANTLR way, thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say there's no way for ANTLR to handle this.  The "yada, yada" part of this question makes it difficult to provide a concrete example of how to handle this precise situation.  It does show hallmarks of having been cobbled together over time (JCL goes back a LONG ways, I recall zOS JCL).  One thing that's not obvious is whether there is a consistent tokenization strategy, you may have to have several lexer modes.  With specific examples, we can probably provide guidance, but it doesn't look like it'll be "messy" no matter how you go about it.

Comment: I am pretty sure it'd need a number of lexer modes. If I can get guidance for the concrete examle above I am confident I can derive everything else from that. So that example would be "COPY-FILE FROM-FILE=fromfilename,TO-FILE=tofilename" and its (non-documented, but working !) alternative "COPY-FILE fromfilename,tofilename" where both "fromfilename" and "tofilename" would need to be consumed as a single string, no matter what strange chars it got. I can see whitespace, comma and newline as possible delimiters.

Comment: For some extra fun: a right paren is, for some commands / parameters, a valid delimiter as well, but only if it is the 2nd one, because when you know z/OS JCL file names can come as MY.FILE(+2) with the number in brackets being the generation number. This is possible here as well, so as in my initial "synthetical" example FILE=(MY.FILE(+2)) would be valid for some JCL elements.